# jquery scroll to element not working - scrolls to random places

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

There are many stackoverflow questions regarding this but I couldn't find my answer. I have this javascript code:

```
$(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

        $('html,body, .main').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 10
        }, 1000);

      });
    });
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"><!--<![endif]-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="common.css">
    <script src="responsive-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/extraScripts.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <div role="navigation" id="foo" class="nav-collapse">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Equipo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Sistemas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Desarrollo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

<div role="main" class="main">

    <a href="#nav" class="nav-toggle">Menu</a>

    <div class = "section" id = "section1" >

        <!-- some stuff -->

    </div> 

    <div class = "section" id = "section2">

        <!-- some stuff -->

    </div>  

    <div class = "section" id = "section3">

      <!-- some stuff -->

    </div>

    <div class = "section" id = "section4" >

            <!-- some stuff -->
    </div>

</div>  

<script>
  var navigation = responsiveNav("foo", {customToggle: ".nav-toggle"});
</script>

  </body>

</html>
```

So I am using a template I found online. It has a fancy menu on the left and then a main content on the middle. Everything is inside:

```
<div role="main" class="main"> </div>
```

I want that when a link on the menu is clicked, it scrolls to the particular sections (#section1, #section2, #section3, #section4). Right now it works the first time I click on one of the links but the second time it goes to a random place.

Any clues why this might be happening?

--- UPDATE ----

I tried all of the solutions mentioned and it is not working. I think it has to do with the CSS that I have for the main container (class .main). Take a look at the code (I took this code from the library I am using):

```
.main {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  padding: 3em 4em;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0, .6);
  top: .8em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 76%;
  background: #fff;
}

.main::-webkit-scrollbar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .15);
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
}

.main::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .4);
}
```

I tried removing the CSS code above and using this and it works:

```
$(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

        $('html,body, .main').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - 10
        }, 1000);

      });
    });
```

But I need that CSS. Any clue how I can fix it?

Comment: The `this` in `$(this.hash)` is the `html/body` and not `<a>`. Store it in a variable above the animate and then pass the value.

Comment: Your code works correct https://jsfiddle.net/rwfLn6vy/ with enough body height

Comment: @Mihail it is not working. I think it has to do with the CSS I have for my menu (External code). I will post the code now

Comment: So it looks like the problem is the container .main has a position:fixed. If I remove that, it works fine. Having the position fixed it what lets me has the fancy menu on the left. What can I do with Javascript to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was that you had a strange call to the context of the link clicked `$(this.hash)`. Changing to `that = $(this)` outside the closure solved the problem.

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    $('html,body, .main').animate({
      scrollTop: that.offset().top - 10
    }, 1000);

  });
});
```

Here is a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SjlDO7YpYIrMFDromFq3?p=preview)

Later on!!

Comment: It is not working. I think it has to do with the CSS that I am using for my menu. I will post the CSS code now